# Python: GtkMenuItem packing with GtkBox and 2 labels

Tags: python, xml, gtk, pygobject, appindicator

I'm using Gtk.Builder() to build an AppIndicator's menu. The goal is to have a MenuItem with two labels inside it (one on the left and one on the right), but for some reason, the second label gets ignored and only the first one is rendered correctly. I'm pretty certain its possible, because Gnome documentation says so and DateTime widget on Ubuntu have the same kind of MenuItem in it.

```
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
    <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
    <object class="GtkMenu">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
            <object class="GtkMenuItem">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <child>
                    <object class="GtkBox" id="box">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkLabel">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Label 1</property>
                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                <property name="halign">start</property>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                        <child>
                            <object class="GtkLabel">
                                <property name="visible">True</property>
                                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Label 2</property>
                                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                                <property name="halign">end</property>
                            </object>
                        </child>
                    </object>
                </child>
            </object>
        </child>
    </object>
</interface>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What Ubuntu DateTime control?

Comment: @andlabs, [this one](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/timezones-300x180.jpg).

Comment: Ah, that's GtkCalendar. I don't think Unity uses GMenus, does it? You can check the panel source code to see how that item is done.

Comment: Have you figured this out independently in the past week or so?

Comment: @andlabs, no, unfortunately. As I understood, it's a limitation of PyGObject. GtkCalendar does it in a more native way. I'm not so good at C, so I couldn't find the exact layout definition.